# How to save a group (array) of images into firebase cloud storage?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am attempting to save an array of images the user took into cloud storage and then save a URL to that image under that persons profile. How can I do this? Currently I wrote the code bellow which save one images at a time taken by the user but I was told this was a bad way of doing it. Additionally images are not being added but replacing the one before it.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        // let imageToUse = PhotoArray()
        // let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userPickedImage) //here convert to data
       PhotoArray.sharedInstance.photosArray.append(userPickedImage)  //append converted data in array

        //                do {
        //                    try realm.write {
        //                        realm.add(imageToUse)
        //                    }
        //                } catch {
        //                    print(“error adding image to array\(error)“)
        //                }

            imageView.image = userPickedImage
//-----------------------------//
            //Create a reference to the image
            let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("image.jpg")

            // Get image data
            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(userPickedImage) {

                // Upload image to Firebase Cloud Storage
                imageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    guard error == nil else {
                        // Handle error
                        return
                    }
                    // Get full image url
                    imageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                        guard let downloadURL = url else {
                            // Handle error
                            return
                        }

                        // Save url to database
                        Firestore.firestore().collection("images").document("myImage").setData(["imageUrl" : downloadURL.absoluteString])
                    }
                }
            }
//-----------------------------//
        }
    // print(PhotoArray().photosArray.count)
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the firebase docs:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("cities").addDocument(data: [
"name": "Tokyo",
"country": "Japan"
]) { err in
if let err = err {
    print("Error adding document: \(err)")
} else {
    print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
}
}
```

Hope this will help you. 
You can read about here: [Click me](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Comment: Where shoudl this be implemeted